# How to resolve memory Error in Python 3.6 with 64 bit Windows and 8GB RAM?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, out-of-memory, ram

I have 2 dataframes of shape (70661802, 3) and (8264276, 14). I have to merge them based on columns but unable to do so as I get memory error.

MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

The RAM on my machine is 8GB and the python is running on 64 bit (checked with platform.architecture).

Could not try anything else as I am getting memory error.

%time df_raw_1 = df_raw_train.merge(df_raw_user, left_on='node1_id', right_on='node_id', how='inner', suffixes=('', '_node1'))